# Nash Equilibrium Static or Dynamic? Poker player help!

Tags: probability-theory, nash-equilibrium

My buddy and I are professional poker players, we began quite a solid debate tonight and I’d be curious as to what the forum has to say.

Is the Nash equilibrium (GTO in Poker terms) a dynamically changing equilibrium or a static one? Does the GTO strategy for a particular poker game change based on player information attained?

Upon entering an unknown poker game, GTO is the exact same for all games with unknown opponents. However, does GTO (Nash equilibrium) change for a poker game with given information?

An example would be, we know Player A to only go all in with AA and no other hand, the broad GTO decision is to call off his all in with QQ/KK/AA but does the GTO strategy deviate to now include folding anything but AA, which is only good for a chop?

Answer (score 0):

GTO is static and will play all players the same way for all time so it will continue to call off player A with  QQ/KK/AA